# Is there a way to customize pagination using the reactable library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, sass

I'm creating pagination for a reactable table. Adding the pagination functionality is clearly state in the docs, using `itemsPerPage` and `pageButtonLimit`:

```
<Table className="table" data={[
    { Name: 'Griffin Smith', Age: '18' },
    { Age: '23',  Name: 'Lee Salminen' },
    { Age: '28', Position: 'Developer' },
    { Name: 'Griffin Smith', Age: '18' },
    { Age: '30',  Name: 'Test Person' },
    { Name: 'Another Test', Age: '26', Position: 'Developer' },
    { Name: 'Third Test', Age: '19', Position: 'Salesperson' },
    { Age: '23',  Name: 'End of this Page', Position: 'CEO' },
]} itemsPerPage={4} pageButtonLimit={5} />
```

However, the challenging aspect of the pagination is, being able to customize the look and feel of the pagination container. I am using the following class `reactable-pagination` to customize the pagination container. However, this is quite challenging because it effects the look of the table.

I reviewed the following GitHub Issue, but it did not seem to resolve my issue. [Make it possible to style pagination](https://github.com/glittershark/reactable/issues/4)

I'm using React and Sass, so please DO NOT respond with jQuery DOM manipulation answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my response to the issue https://github.com/glittershark/reactable/issues/4#issuecomment-289592348

and here is the diff of where I stuck the classes
https://github.com/glittershark/reactable/commit/8e3b32c9fde776628f4caf84160f410a682cff10

Comment: Since, this is still a PR, and not an integrated part of the library, did you override the module directly in the node module? If this is the case, how do you handle any updates to the library in the future? Also, I'm using foundation, not bootstrap.

Comment: I forked it, committed the changes to my fork, then brought the fork in through my `package.json`: `"reactable": "github:kevincolten/reactable#8e3b32c"`